# Mockups for room design

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, graphic-design

I am looking for a software (preferable offline) in Windows or Linux for room mockups. I want to design a room without using Photoshop or Illustator. I had a similar one for Website Mockups. Look for example here: [Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups/)

- Basic functionality: Room/environment mockup
- Platform: Windows/Linux
- Free version or paid with a free testing period

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Sweet Home 3D

Take a look at [Sweet Home 3D](http://www.sweethome3d.com/). Been around for many years.

It does 2D drawings like in your example, but can also show it in 3D (hence the name!). The app actually transforms your 2D drawings into 3D. You can stick with simple wireframe sketches or you can get fancy with realistic finishes. You can even record a video of a walk-through in your virtual space!

The app is explicitly built for floorplans and building layout. So it comes with pre-defined components such as interior walls, exterior walls, doors, windows, chairs & tables, appliances, and so on. You just drag and drop, fidget and tweak. No need to be a skilled designer or artist.

See [Gallery](http://www.sweethome3d.com/gallery.jsp) of screen shots.

It's free-of-cost and open-source, released under the [GPL 2 licence](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt). Built on the [Java platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)#Java_platform), so it runs on multiple platforms including Linux, Mac OS X, Windows, and more.

[image: example 2D condo floor]

[image: projected 3D floor plan]

[image: example realistic room in condo]

[image: screen shot of example window in Sweet Home 3D app]

Comment: I've used it and would have written a recommendation for it. Could you expand on yours if you have already used it? Its a bit thin currently. (Although the program is good)